# How to setup nuxtjs with nginx in Docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want setup my nuxtjs together with nginx in my docker file. However, it shows the default page nginx, which says 'Welcome to nginx'. Supposely , i should be viewing my website but instead it show the default page of nginx. May i know why is this happening?

docker file

```
FROM node:16.14.0-alpine3.15 as builder
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN yarn install \
  --prefer-offline \
  --frozen-lockfile \
  --non-interactive \
  --production=false

RUN yarn generate

RUN rm -rf node_modules && \
  NODE_ENV=production yarn install \
  --prefer-offline \
  --pure-lockfile \
  --non-interactive \
  --production=true

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=builder /app/ .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
      build:
        context: ./frontend
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
            max-file: "5"
            max-size: 50m
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
          - 3001:80
```

Comment: did you change your nginx configuration? Everything was fine before and became broken after upgrade?

Comment: nope i do not have nginx configuration

Comment: it keep returns the default page of nginx , not sure why

Comment: you need to pass some configuration directives to nginx, so it can start to serve your application, otherwise you will get default configuration and default page.

Comment: do i have to create nginx.conf file in my directory ?

Comment: ` COPY --from=builder /app/.output/public /usr/share/nginx/html ` i added this line in my docker but it kept showing `failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount931975545/app/.output: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount931975545/app/.output `

Comment: this answer from official Docker forum might be helpful: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-yml-services-for-nginx/52562/2